# bit parity code needs explanation as to how it works?

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor, bit-shift, parity

Here is the code that reports the `bit parity` of a given integer:

```
01: bool parity(unsigned int x)
02: {
03:   x ^= x >> 16;
04:   x ^= x >>  8;
05:   x ^= x >>  4;
06:   x &= 0x0F;
07:   return ((0x6996 >> x) & 1) != 0;
08: }
```

I found this [here.](http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/parity.html). while there seems to be explanation in the link, I do not understand.
The first explanation that start with `The code first "merges" bits 0 − 15 with bits 16 − 31 using a right shift and XOR (line 3).` is making it hard for me to understand as to what is going on. I tried to play around them but that did not help. if a clarity on how this work is given, it will be useful for beginners like me
Thanks

EDIT: from post below:

```
value      : 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
value >> 16: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1110 1010 1101
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : 1101 1110 1010 1101 0110 0001 0100 0010
```

now right shift this again by 8 bits:

```
value          : 1101 1110 1010 1101 0110 0001 0100 0010
value >>8      : 0000 0000 1101 1110 1010 1101 0110 0001
 ----------------------------------------------------
xor            : 1101 1110 1110 0001 0100 1100 0010 0011
```

so where is the merging of parity happening here?

Comment: Bit parity is simply XORing all the bits together.  The above does it in "chunks" to make it faster and simpler, other than that last line which is definitely a bit weird.  However, at that point the parity has been reduced to a 4-bit quantity in `x`, and so that last line is basically "looking up" the correct parity value for one of 16 possible values in `x` -- a clever, if obscure, short-cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start first with a 2-bit example so you can see what's going on. The four possibilities are:

```
ab  a^b
--  ---
00   0
01   1
10   1
11   0
```

You can see that `a^b (xor)` gives 0 for an even number of one-bits and 1 for an odd number. This woks for 3-bit values as well:

```
abc  a^b^c
---  -----
000    0
001    1
010    1
011    0
100    1
101    0
110    0
111    1
```

The same trick is being used in lines 3 through 6 to merge all 32 bits into a single 4-bit value. Line 3 merges `b31-16` with `b15-0` to give a 16-bit value, then line 4 merges the resultant `b15-b8` with `b7-b0`, then line 5 merges the resultant `b7-b4` with `b3-b0`. Since `b31-b4` (the upper half of each xor operation) aren't cleared by that operations, line 6 takes care of that by clearing them out (anding with binary `0000...1111` to clear all but the lower 4 bits).

The merging here is achieved in a chunking mode. By "chunking", I mean that it treats the value in reducing chunks rather than as individual bits, which allows it to efficiently reduce the value to a 4-bit size (it can do this because the xor operation is both associative and commutative). The alternative would be to perform seven xor operations on the nybbles rather than three. Or, in complexity analysis terms, O(log n) instead of O(n).

Say you have the value `0xdeadbeef`, which is binary `1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111`. The merging happens thus:

```
value      : 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
      >> 16: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1110 1010 1101
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... 0110 0001 0100 0010
```

(with the irrelevant bits, those which will not be used in future, left as `.` characters).

For the *complete* operation:

```
value      : 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
      >> 16: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1110 1010 1101
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... 0110 0001 0100 0010
      >>  8: .... .... .... .... 0000 0000 0110 0011
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... .... .... 0010 0001
      >>  4: .... .... .... .... .... .... 0000 0010
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0011
```

And, looking up `0011` in the table below, we see that it gives even parity (there are 24 1-bits in the original value). Changing just *one* bit in that original value (any bit, I've chosen the righmost bit) will result in the opposite case:

```
value      : 1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1110
      >> 16: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1110 1010 1101
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... 0110 0001 0100 0011
      >>  8: .... .... .... .... 0000 0000 0110 0011
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... .... .... 0010 0000
      >>  4: .... .... .... .... .... .... 0000 0010
----------------------------------------------------
xor        : .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0010
```

And `0010` in the below table is odd parity.

The only "magic" there is the `0x6996` value which is shifted by the four-bit value to ensure the lower bit is set appropriately, then *that* bit is used to decide the parity. The reason `0x6996` (binary `0110 1001 1001 0110`) is used is because of the nature of parity for binary values as shown in the lined page:

```
Val  Bnry  #1bits  parity (1=odd)
---  ----  ------  --------------
                         +------> 0x6996
                         |
  0  0000     0    even (0)
  1  0001     1    odd  (1)
  2  0010     1    odd  (1)
  3  0011     2    even (0)
  4  0100     1    odd  (1)
  5  0101     2    even (0)
  6  0110     2    even (0)
  7  0111     3    odd  (1)
  8  1000     1    odd  (1)
  9  1001     2    even (0)
 10  1010     2    even (0)
 11  1011     3    odd  (1)
 12  1100     2    even (0)
 13  1101     3    odd  (1)
 14  1110     3    odd  (1)
 15  1111     4    even (0)
```

Note that it's not *necessary* to do the final shift-of-a-constant. You *could* just as easily continue the merging operations until you get down to a single bit, then use that bit:

```
bool parity (unsigned int x) {
  x ^= x >> 16;
  x ^= x >>  8;
  x ^= x >>  4;
  x ^= x >>  2;
  x ^= x >>  1;
  return x & 1;
}
```

However, once you have the value `0...15`, a shift of a constant by that value is likely to be faster than two extra shift-and-xor operations.

Comment: Q1: how does merging of 32 to 16 to 8 to 4 to 2 happens? can you briefly explain. I understood `XOR`ing even number of bits give zero and one otherwise

Comment: what happens in line 6?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: I've added further explanation of those two points which will hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: you mentioned `zero/irrelevent bits left blank`. but when you right shift, you fill the `zeroes` on the right side, and when you `xor`, x and x>>16, the result will not be blank right?

Comment: @eagertoLearn, bad explanation on my part, I've cleaned it up. When you right shift, zero-bits are pushed in from the _left_ side, not the right. I'll also expand on the example all the way down to four bits.

Comment: woow! great explanation. I kind of understood. Is there a typo here `And, looking up 0001` while it must `And, looking up 0011`. and why is the need to look up the table? can I just count the bits (it is two) and hence the `parity is even(0)`

Comment: again, this could be a stupid question, why stop with `0010` why not go all the way to two bits `10` and just count the `1 bits`

Comment: @eagertoLearn, good catch, I've fixed that value up. The final constant shift is simply a quick operation once you get down to a value you can shift the constant by safely (0...15). You _could_ count the 1-bits by continuing with `x ^ x >> 2; x ^= x >> 1;` but it's likely to be more inefficient. Updating the answer with that info as well.

Comment: In the last method you wrote, you are not clearing `the first 31 bits` correct? I think it is not necessary to clear them anyway in this case.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: correct. You don't need to clear them in that case since you're only returning the lower bit anyway: `return x & 1;`.

Comment: great! Thank you very much. one last question, here we are dealing with unsigned integers, are there any potential problems if I pass in negative numbers (they are signed at 32nd bit right)

Comment: Yes, there are potential problems. Right shifting of negative values is an implementation defined thing (C11 6.5.7/5) so may not work portably. Best to cast to unsigned either implicitly via the function prototype (as `parity()` does) or explicitly in the function call.

Comment: may be I should rise a seperate question on bit parity for signed integers?

Comment: @eagertoLearn, you _could,_ but I wouldn't worry. That code will work fine with signed `int` values because they'll be cast to the unsigned variant by the prototype (possibly weird variations like one's complement and sign/magnitude encoding notwithstanding of course but they're so rare as to be irrelevant). But, it may also help out future visitors to the site so feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2):

From the original page,

> Bit parity tells whether a given input contains an odd number of 1's.

So you want to add up the number of 1's.  The code uses the xor operator to add pairs of bits,

```
0^1 = 1 bits on
1^0 = 1 bits on
0^0 = 0 bits on
1^1 = 0 bits on (well, 2, but we cast off 2's)
```

So the first three lines count up the number of 1's (tossing pairs of 1's).

*That should help...*

And notice from the original page, the description of why 0x6996,

> If we encode even by 0 and odd by 1 beginning with parity(15) then we
>   get 0110 1001 0110 1001 = 0x6996, which is the magic number found in
>   line 7. The shift moves the relevant bit to bit 0. Then everything
>   except for bit 0 is masked out. In the end, we get 0 for even and 1
>   for odd, exactly as desired.